# Dynamic node adding breaks drag behavior in D3 Force Layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I've implemented force layout and it's working well. However, the problem is, dragging one element doesn't pull other elements. I didn't assign `fixed:true` property so that is not the problem.

Here is [what I did](http://jsfiddle.net/meanyack/f0w74g9f/12/). As you see, dragging one element doesn't fully affect the others. For example, pulling one node to the right doesn't move the other nodes to the right. But what I want to do is like [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/meanyack/2nhTD/116/).

Comment: I do not see your fiddle running, could you fix it?